# Jquery tableDnD - How to create an ajax with ID and position ondrop?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Initialise the table
    $('#admintabel').tableDnD({
        onDrop: function(table, row) {

        }
    });

});
</script>
```

How do I create an ajax call to example `/sort` with the parameters position and ID in a has like this: `[position, ID]` onDrop? And how should my table be like.

**Update:**

I am trying to create an array like:

```
BREDBANDS[id]   1
BREDBANDS[id]   2
BREDBANDS[id]   3
```

My current test data:

```
data: {
                  BREDBANDS: [1, 2, 3]                  },
```

And it is posting this:

```
BREDBANDS[] 1
BREDBANDS[] 2
BREDBANDS[] 3
```

Which is giving a 500 error.

My Rails action which the data is posted to:

```
  def sort
  params[:bredbands].each_with_index do |id, index|
    Bredband.update_all(['position=?', index+1], ['id=?', id])
  end
  render :nothing => true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you're actually asking but making an Ajax request should be done in any of these two ways:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/sort?" + $.tableDnD.serialize(),
    success: function(){
        ...
    }
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/sort",
    data: $("tr", "$admintabel").map(function(){
        return this.id;
    }),
    success: function(){
        ...
    }
});
```

But as it seems you need to provide IDs to your `TR` elements. Then you should be able to call this:

```
$.tableDnD.serialize();
```

which will serialize data of the table and it's row IDs.

Comment: How post an array of all the IDS?

Comment: Here is my table http://pastie.org/2675438 I want to post the IDS and in my action I call with index to update the order.

Comment: @Railsbeginner: Check my edited answer. And check taleDnD examples and code behind them and you'll see how it works.

Comment: I have updated my question. I am trying to create the correct post request that not triggers a 500 error.